# jQuery multiple event handler on iOS Safari

Tags: jquery, ios, safari, event-handling

So I need to make list elements selectable by clicking and ediatble by draging (swiping) - you know the phonestyle.

After experimenting with countless plugins I figured I need to make a simple one that only does what I need it to: http://jsfiddle.net/Ltz6X/

```
$('ul').on("click","li", function(){
    $('ul li').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("selected");
    });
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});

$('ul').on('mousedown', 'li', function(event){
    var start_pos = (event.pageX);
    $(this).bind("mousemove", function(e){
        if (start_pos - e.pageX < -20){
            $(this).children().show(200);
            $(this).unbind("mousemove");
        };
        if (start_pos - e.pageX > 20){
            $(this).children().hide(200);
            $(this).unbind("mousemove");
        };
    });
    $(this).on("mouseup", function(){
        $(this).unbind("mousemove mouseup");
    });
});
```

Works perfect!!!... on chrome :(
But it seems that only one handler at a time works with iOS Safari browser.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Just to clarify. You mean that when you swipe on an `li` it doesnt turn orange?

Comment: @PedroEstrada I click `li`, it turns orage. I swipe it and red "edit" button appears right before it

Comment: yeah, it works like that on safari for me

Comment: **Side Note:** you can use `$('ul li').removeClass("selected");` instead of the `$('ul li').each(...)`